PyQt5 Code Completion for "code-like" syntax
I am trying to create a GUI (with PyQt5) text completion functionality, which supports something akin to a programming IDE, where I have objects and the objects have fields and subfields, which are accessed through a ".". So for example, if the user type "obj.fi", I would like it to suggest "field1", and if the user types "obj.field1.s" it should suggest "subfield1, subfield2 etc..."
I have been able to somewhat get it working on a QLineEdit widget, using the following script:
import sys, re

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QCompleter

test_model_data = [
    ('obj1',[ ('field1',[('subfield1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj2',[ ('field1',[('subfiedl1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj3',[]),
    ('music',[('melody',[]), 
              ('harmony',[('chords',[]),
                          ('rythm',[])])])
]

class CodeCompleter(QCompleter):
    ConcatenationRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.createModel(data)
        
        # Pattern to match the "last word" of an expression
        # Must start with a letter, and be followed by any number of letter,numbers, undrscores or periods(.)
        self.rePtrn = re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$')
        
    def splitPath(self, path):
        ''' This function gets called when the text changes, 
        and we need to select how the new text is to be used to filter options
        '''
        lastWord = (self.rePtrn.findall(path) + [''])[0] #Append empty string, to deal with empty list exception
        return lastWord.split('.')

    def pathFromIndex(self, ix):
        ''' This function is responsible for generating the "autocompletedText"
        Whatever this function returns is the final text on the widget
        '''
        currentText = self.widget().text()
        completionText = ix.data(CodeCompleter.ConcatenationRole)
        
        newText, wasFound = self.rePtrn.subn(completionText, currentText)
        if not wasFound:
            newText = currentText + completionText
            
        return newText

    def createModel(self, data):
        
        def addItems(parent, elements, t=""):
            for text, children in elements:
                item = QStandardItem(text)
                data = t + "." + text if t else text
                item.setData(data)#, CodeCompleter.ConcatenationRole)
                parent.appendRow(item)
                if children:
                    addItems(item, children, data)
                    
        model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        addItems(model, data)
        self.setModel(model)
    
class mainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.completer = CodeCompleter(test_model_data, self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        for i in range(5):
            entry = QLineEdit(self)
            entry.setCompleter(self.completer)
            layout.addWidget(entry)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    hwind = mainApp()
    hwind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

However, this still has some issues. In particular, I may not always want to have the suggestions on the "last word", but actually on the "current word" as in, where the cursor is currently. And secondly, I also might prefer a QTextEdit widget, as the multiline functionality might be required for this afterwall.
When I tried to address both these issues, I completely hit a wall. It seems the QCompleter must be setup completely differently for QTextEdit than it is for a QLineEdit, and it was not very clear why that was the case.
The best I could do was this:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QCompleter, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem, QPalette

test_model_data = [
    ('obj1',[ ('field1',[('subfield1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj2',[ ('field1',[('subfiedl1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj3',[]),
    ('music',[('melody',[]), 
              ('harmony',[('chords',[]),
                          ('rythm',[])])])
]



class CustomCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QCompleter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.createModel(test_model_data)
        
    def createModel(self, data):
        
        def addItems(parent, elements, t=""):
            for text, children in elements:
                item = QStandardItem(text)
                data = t + "." + text if t else text
                item.setData(data)#, CodeCompleter.ConcatenationRole)
                parent.appendRow(item)
                if children:
                    addItems(item, children, data)
                    
        model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        model.splitPath = lambda t: print(t)
        addItems(model, data)
        self.setModel(model)
    
    def splitPaths(self, path):
        print(path)
    
    def complete(self, rect, prefix):
        self.setCompletionPrefix(prefix)
        super().complete(rect)

class CustomTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, idx, completer, initial_text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(initial_text, *args, **kwargs)
        self.completer = completer
        self.idx = idx 
        
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab:  # Show suggestions when Tab is pressed
            self.showSuggestions()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_Return and self.completer.popup().isVisible():  # Replace suggestion when Enter is pressed
            
            self.insertCompletion()
            self.completer.popup().hide()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def insertCompletion(self):
        if not self.completer.widget() is self: return
        
        popup_index = self.completer.popup().currentIndex()
        completion = self.completer.popup().model().data(popup_index)
        
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.StartOfWord)
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.EndOfWord, cursor.KeepAnchor)
        cursor.insertText(completion)

    def currentWord(self):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.WordLeft)
        cursor.select(cursor.WordUnderCursor)
        word = cursor.selectedText()
        #print('Cur word: "%s"' %word)
        return word
    
    def showSuggestions(self):
        cursor_rect = self.cursorRect()
        popup_height = self.completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0)  # Get the height of the popup
        popup_size = self.completer.popup().sizeHint()
        popup_rect = QRect(cursor_rect.bottomRight(), popup_size)
        popup_rect.setHeight(popup_height)  # Set the height of the popup
        popup_rect.moveTop(popup_rect.top() - popup_height)  # Move the top of the popup
        
        #print( popup_rect )
        #self.completer.setWidget(None)
        self.completer.setWidget(self)
        self.completer.complete(popup_rect, self.currentWord())  # Show popup with suggestions
        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        completer = CustomCompleter()
        
        # Create multiple text widgets and connect them to the same completer instance
        text_edit1 = CustomTextEdit(1, completer, "Hello my friend")
        text_edit2 = CustomTextEdit(2, completer, "For lunch we have fruit")
        text_edit3 = CustomTextEdit(3, completer, "And then maybe a movie")


        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Type below (press Tab for suggestions, Enter to replace):"))
        layout.addWidget(text_edit1)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit2)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit3)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Multiline Textbox with Dropdown")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Which at least has the functionality working on the "current word", and also on a multiline QEditText widget. However, I completely lost the functionality of the "nested" fields. The "splitPath" function seems to be completely ignored in this method, and I cannot find any suitable way to "filter" my suggestions based on the "split path" methodology (other than rewriting the whole model/search/filter from scratch).
Is there any good way to be able to send to the completer the "current object word" (e.g. "obj1.field1.su" ), and have it match through the QStandardItemModel using the "splitPath" breaking it at '.' chars, like in the previous example?

TYPO: def splitPaths --> def splitPath.

WordLeft and WordUnderCursor are inappropriate. The former will move to the left word even if there are spaces after that, and the latter will only select a single word, not the whole "path". You need to find proper cursor movements that match the [word.]word syntax (a proper regex may be needed) and also consider that the cursor might be in the middle of that.

I am not super happy with this answer. Basically I had to write my own nested model, which works with a wrapper on the QStringModel. I also had to modify the QCompleter to work with it. I feel like I am not fully/properly utilizing the PyQt5 library, out of my own ignorance, and I am doing quite a lot on Python, which I fear my affect performance a bit.
But it is currently doing what the original question was asking, so I will leave it here in case it might help someone else with the same issue:
import sys
import re

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QCompleter, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QStringListModel, QPropertyAnimation

test_model_data = [
    ('obj1',[ ('field1',[('subfield1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj2',[ ('field1',[('subfiedl1',[])]),
              ('field2',[])]),                        
    ('obj3',[]),
    ('music',[('melody',[]), 
              ('harmony',[('chords',[]),
                          ('rythm',[])])])
]


class NestedDictCompleteModel:
    ''' This wraps a QStringModel so that it allows for recursive models, 
    supporting a syntax of "obj.field.subfield.subSubfield"
    It creates a recursive Dict structure, to search through the fields quickly
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.itemDict = {}
        self.stringModel = QStringListModel()
        
    def addItem(self, itemData):
        ''' Creates a new Item at this level with the text=itemData
        Returns the "empty" model of the new item, so that it can be used to fill in
        '''
        subModel = NestedDictCompleteModel()
        self.itemDict[ itemData ] = subModel
        
        n = self.stringModel.rowCount()
        self.stringModel.insertRows(n, 1)
        self.stringModel.setData( self.stringModel.index(n), itemData)
    
        return subModel
    
    def filterByWords(self, words):
        if len(words)<2: 
            return self.stringModel
        if not words[0] in self.itemDict:
            return QStringListModel() # Empty model
        
        return self.itemDict[ words[0] ].filterByWords( words[1:] )
        
class CustomCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QCompleter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.mainModel = self.createModel(test_model_data)
        self.setModel( self.mainModel.stringModel )
    def createModel(self, data):
        
        def addItems(parent, elements, t=""):
            for text, children in elements:
                item = parent.addItem( text )
                if children:
                    addItems(item, children, data)
                    
        model = NestedDictCompleteModel()
        addItems(model, data)
        
        return model 
    
    def complete(self, rect, prefix):
        #New Model, based on recursive model searching on ['objName', 'fieldName', 'subFieldName' etc...]
        words = prefix.split('.')
        model = self.mainModel.filterByWords( words )
        
        self.setModel( model )
        self.setCompletionPrefix( words[-1] ) # Filter the current model dynamically based on last word
        
        super().complete(rect)
        
class CustomTextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, idx, completer, initial_text, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(initial_text, *args, **kwargs)
        self.completer = completer
        self.idx = idx 
        
        self.heightInFocus = kwargs.get('heightInFocus', 5)
        self.heightOutFocus = kwargs.get('heightInFocus', 1)
        self.setHeightLines(self.heightOutFocus, anim=False)
        
        self.animDur = 200 #100miliseconds
        self.textChanged.connect(self.showSuggestions)
        
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)
        
        self.blockEventFocus = False # Prevent
        
        # Regex to match all "words.subWords" to the left/right of the string
        self.reLeftAll = re.compile( r'.*?(?P<lw>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)$' )
        self.reRightAll = re.compile( r'^(?P<rw>[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)' )
        
        # Regex to match single "subWord" to the left/right of the string
        self.reLeft = re.compile( r'.*?(?P<lw>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$' )
        self.reRight = re.compile( r'^(?P<rw>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)' )
        
    def isolateFocusWord(self, allTerms=True):
        ''' In the current text, finds the "words.subWord" around the current cursor.
        Returns the word.subword string, as well the the indexes for start and end,
        in the whole text
        '''
        text = self.toPlainText()
        ti = self.textCursor().positionInBlock() # index of the cursor in text
        
        textLeft, textRight = text[:ti], text[ti:]
        
        if allTerms:
            ml = self.reLeftAll.match(textLeft)
            mr = self.reRightAll.match(textRight)
        else:
            ml = self.reLeft.match(textLeft)
            mr = self.reRight.match(textRight)
        
        wl = ml.group(1) if ml else ''
        wr = mr.group(1) if mr else ''
        
        return wl+wr, ti-len(wl), ti+len(wr)
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return and self.completer.popup().isVisible():  # Replace suggestion when Enter is pressed
            self.insertCompletion()
            self.completer.popup().hide()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def insertCompletion(self):
        ''' Finds the current selected suggestion and replaces it in the text,
        by replacing the current "subword"
        '''
        if not self.completer.widget() is self: return
        
        popup_index = self.completer.popup().currentIndex()
        completion = self.completer.popup().model().data(popup_index)
        
        w, si, ei = self.isolateFocusWord(allTerms=False)
        
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(si, cursor.MoveAnchor)#cursor.StartOfWord)
        cursor.setPosition(ei, cursor.KeepAnchor) #cursor.EndOfWord, cursor.KeepAnchor)
        cursor.insertText(completion)
        
    def showSuggestions(self):
        # Find the "word.subword" at the cursor
        focusWord, li,ri = self.isolateFocusWord()
        
        self.blockEventFocus = True
        
        cursor_rect = self.cursorRect()
        
        popup_height = self.completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0)  # Get the height of the popup
        popup_size = self.completer.popup().sizeHint()
        popup_rect = QRect(cursor_rect.bottomRight(), popup_size)
        popup_rect.setHeight(popup_height)  # Set the height of the popup
        newTop = popup_rect.top() - popup_height
        popup_rect.moveTop(newTop)  # Move the top of the popup
        
        self.completer.setWidget(self)
        self.completer.complete(popup_rect, focusWord )  # Show popup with suggestions
        self.blockEventFocus = False
    
    def setHeightLines(self, nlines, anim=True):
        line_height = self.fontMetrics().lineSpacing()
        height = (nlines+1) * line_height
        
        if anim:
            animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
            animation.setDuration(self.animDur)  # Duration of the animation in milliseconds
            animation.setStartValue(self.height())
            animation.setEndValue(height)
    
            # Start the animation
            animation.start()
            
            animation2 = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
            animation2.setDuration(self.animDur)  # Duration of the animation in milliseconds
            animation2.setStartValue(self.height())
            animation2.setEndValue(height)
    
            # Start the animation
            animation2.start()
            
            self.animations = animation, animation2
        else:
            self.setFixedHeight(height)
            
        
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if self.blockEventFocus: return
        self.setHeightLines(self.heightInFocus)
        super().focusInEvent(event)
    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        if self.blockEventFocus: return
        self.setHeightLines(self.heightOutFocus)
        super().focusOutEvent(event)
        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        completer = CustomCompleter()
        
        btn = QPushButton('Delete obj1')
        
        # Create multiple text widgets and connect them to the same completer instance
        text_edit1 = CustomTextEdit(1, completer, "Here we have obj1.field1  and also obj2")
        text_edit2 = CustomTextEdit(2, completer, "For lunch we have fruit")
        text_edit3 = CustomTextEdit(3, completer, "music is wonderful and obj")


        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Start Typing to see object and field suggestions"))
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit1)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit2)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit3)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Multiline Textbox with Dropdown")
        #self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

